# Деление на ноль для переменных типа float

Tags: c, переменные

Если у меня есть

```
float v = v();
float h = h();
```

а потом я хочу проверять такое условие:

```
if (v<0 && ABS(v/h) > 0.5)
```

то могу ли я быть уверена, что если

```
h==0, то ABS(v/h) == INFINITY и INFINITY точно > 0.5?
```

То есть не нужно ли учитывать, что h может быть равно 0, типа такого:

```
if (h==0 ? v<0 : v<0 && ABS(v/h) > 0.5)
```

?

Comment: Попробуйте скормить ноль и увидите результат, а заодно и ответ н аваш вопрос ;-)

Comment: я пробовала, у меня ABS(v/h) == INFINITY, но вопрос в том гарантировано ли такое поведение?

Comment: вообще то сравнивать вещественное число на равенство чему то другому (в том числе 0) - плохая идея. В большинстве случаев оно будет неравно 0.

Но закладываться на деление на ноль - ещё интереснее.

Comment: А что с делением на ноль? В том и вопрос - безопасно это или нет.

Comment: Нет, это небезопасно. Нужно обрабатывать такие ситуации отдельно.

К чему это может привести: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZ7pUADoo58

Comment: Почему небезопасно? если v/0 гарантировано == INFINITY, а INFINITY гарантировано больше любого float? Где ошибка? Что-то из этого *не* гарантировано? В этом и суть моего вопроса.

Comment: я нигде не видел такой гарантии. А вот то, что будет исключение - это часто гарантируется (при целочисленном делении точно будет, если флагами процессора не поиграть).

Comment: @1101_debian В Вашем первом комментарии Вы предположили, что оно крешнется? Или что будет работать как ожидается? @KoVadim Да, я знаю про целочисленное деление, но вопрос-то именно про float. Потому что у меня стабильно при делении на h==0 выводит в лог значение "inf". Компилятор XCode.

Comment: проверил на gcc - выводит inf, да. Но я бы на эту логику не закладывался.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Частично да. Числа с плавающей точкой подчиняются [стандарту IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#In_computer_arithmetic).

1. Если `v > 0` и `h == 0`, то `v/h == INFINITY`. Гарантировано, что `INFINITY > 0.5`.
2. Если `v < 0` и `h == 0`, то `v/h == -INFINITY`. Для него `-INFINITY < 0.5`.
3. Если `v == 0` и `h == 0`, то `v/h == NaN`. Для него любое сравнение, ЕМНИП, возвращает false.

---

Операции с бесконечными значениями строго определены в C стандартом IEEE-754. Так что ваш код верен.

---

При работе с плавающей запятой контроль за делением на ноль по умолчанию отключён, и деление на ноль даёт бесконечность или NaN. Существует, однако, [метод](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions) *включить* такой контроль. Однако, и в этом случае при делении на ноль не возникнет исключение или какая-то другая ошибка, а лишь будет взведён флаг, который можно опросить вызовом `fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)`.

---

Возможно, вам пригодится функция [`atan2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/atan2):

```
float angle = atan2(h, w);
if (angle < -2*PI/3 && angle > -PI/3) ...
```

Comment: А ABS(-INFINITY) == INFINITY? Если да, то у меня как раз второй случай.

Comment: По идее, да: https://ideone.com/FWwbCD