# Безопасное деление на ноль

Tags: c++, c, float

Как определить допустимое значение переменной типа `float`, используемой в качестве делителя, чтобы избежать ошибки деления на ноль?
Достаточно ли сравнить с нулем?

```
float f;
//...
if (f != 0.f)
    1.f / f;
```

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/219605/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-float) похожий вопрос, где [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) ссылается на [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero#In_computer_arithmetic), где гарантируется:

> Если v > 0 и h == 0, то v/h == INFINITY
>
> Если v < 0 и h == 0, то v/h == -INFINITY

Что в принципе позволит исключить проверку на ноль перед делением, но с другой стороны, [стандарт](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.5.5 говорит:

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the
>   first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is **undefined**.

Вопрос в том, безопасно ли делить `float` с нулями, и если нет, какое должно быть условие проверки, чтобы получить определенный результат.

Comment: Ну, по логике, раз во втором примечании участвует оператор %, то это должно относиться только к целочисленным типам?..

Comment: @Harry ну явно это не прописано, и следуя той же логике, пункт 6.5.5.2 явно говорит что integer это только для %

Comment: Может быть поможет вот эта тема? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915138/comparing-floating-point-0

Comment: 6.5.5.5 явно для целых. Думаю, можно смело делить. Главное, чтобы случайно где-либо приведения к целому не произошло.

Comment: @gecube у меня только черновик N1570, у вас явно прописано про целые в этом параграфе?

Comment: Этот [вопрос на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114498/can-a-near-zero-floating-value-cause-a-divide-by-zero-error) смотрели?

Comment: @alexolut лучше бы не смотрел и по старинке сравнивал с учетом погрешности. После всей этой противоречивой информации какой-то тупик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь хочу отметить, что для выяснения правил работы с числами с плавающей точкой в `c` или `c++` нужно проверить значения соответствующих констант. Т.е. стандарты языков не гарантируют обязательности наличия этих правил, но имеется возможность узнать поддерживает ли та или иная реализация, например, стандарт *IEEE-754* для определенного типа.

В приложении `F` (*IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic*) стандарта языка `c` четко сказано:

> An implementation that
>   defines **__STDC_IEC_559__** shall conform to the specifications in this annex.

В `c++` можно проверить поддержку *IEEE-754* для вещественного типа с помощью такого кода:

```
std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559
```

> True if and only if the type adheres to IEC 559 standard. 
>   International Electrotechnical Commission standard 559 is the same as IEEE 754.

Если поддержка обеспечивается, то дальнейшее исследование вопроса нужно производить уже по упомянутому стандарту. Но как показывает практика, ошибка деления на ноль возникает исключительно при делении на ноль, хотя [получить бесконечность](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VTQSot9Nb0CQ0gfO) можно и при делении на отличное от нуля значение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cfenv>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    float min = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
    volatile float zero = 0.0f;
    std::cout <<  10.f / min << '\n';
    if(std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)) {
        std::cout << "division by zero reported\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "division by zero not reported\n";
    }
}
```

Получим:

> ```
> inf
> division by zero not reported
> ```

Если заменим `min` на `zero`, [то уже](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lzY5zQ5OLIMNeUgp):

> ```
> inf
> division by zero reported
> ```

Поэтому для себя надо решить, чего же действительно хочется избежать: ошибки деления на ноль или получения бесконечности.

Согласно [IEEE-754](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~tsimo1/CMSC455/IEEE-754-2008.pdf) п.7.3 исключение типа "деление на ноль" возникает только при действиях на конечных операндах в двух случаях:

- деление ненулевого значения на ноль;
- вычисление логарифма от нуля.

Comment: Т.е. `assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559)` и никакой неопределенности?

Comment: И ещё такой момент: "как показывает практика, ошибка деления на ноль возникает исключительно при делении на ноль", т.е. явно это не оговаривается, даже при `is_iec559` ?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, добавил ссылку на ieee-754.

Answer (score 4):

Я подозреваю, что Стандарт языка должен опираться на IEEE-754 в вопросах плавающей арифметики, а всё остальное касается только целых чисел. В Стандарте IEEE-754 сказано, что ненулевое значение (в том числе бесконечность) может быть поделено на ноль, результатом будет бесконечность. Деление нуля на ноль тоже допустимо, при этом получим quite NaN, то есть аналог некоей неопределённости.

Согласитесь, было бы странно, что если процессор работает строго по IEEE-754, а компилятор языка - нет.

Далее, если опасаться того, что результат может стать бесконечным, то знаменатель вовсе не обязан быть равным нулю, он может быть, например, равен `0,5`, а числитель чуть больше половины максимально возможного значения. Получается, что для избежании бесконечного ответа, явно недостаточно проверять знаменатель на `0.0f`, нужно заведомо соотнести знаменатель с числителем, а сделать это можно через деление, перед которым, собственно, мы и пытаемся сделать проверку : ) Сомневаюсь, что создатели языка настолько недальновидны, что допустили бы такой промах.

Comment: Про стандарт IEEE-754 понятно, и про создателей языка тоже, но все таки, где в сишном стандарте об этом явно говорится? Пока что вижу только `..the behavior is undefined.`. Хотя возможно, что все компиляторы мира определяют такую ситуацию однозначно.

Comment: Ну а процессор, так вообще может только целочисленные операции поддерживать. Ну Z80 например )

Comment: К сожалению, не имею Стандарта под рукой, но поищите, пожалуйста, там слова о том, что плавающая арифметика подчиняется IEEE-754. Это будет гарантировать то, 6.5.5.5 - это про целые числа. Если такой фразы в Стандарте нет, значит по идее придётся везде писать `if (f!=0.0f)`. Причём одной этой проверки достаточно как для +0, так и для -0 (оба нуля считаются равными).

Comment: Если процессор поддерживает только целые числа, то язык по логике вещей обязан предоставить софтварную реализацию плавающей точки.

Comment: Про процессор это к тому, что "Согласитесь, было бы странно, что если процессор работает строго по IEEE-754, а компилятор языка - нет." в этом случае как аргумент не очень.

Comment: Я Вас понял, но поясню мысль: почти все самые распространённые процессоры поддерживают IEEE-754 по умолчанию. Было бы странно, если бы один из самых распространённых языков как Си имел бы какие-то другие соглашения о плавающей точке. Поэтому даже если в процессоре такой арифметики нет, создатели компилятора создают собственную программную реализацию float и double.

Comment: Ну я бы не удивился бы, если бы были другие соглашения. Т.к. в свое время самые распространенные процессоры были целочисленными. Другое дело, что стандарт могли бы и привести к современным реалиям, все таки стандарт 11.

Comment: Кстати, судя по профилю это ваша специализация, не могли бы подкинуть ссылку на 101 для самых маленьких про плавающие точки?

Comment: Я не имею права дать вам публично текст Стандарта, так как он у Intel платный, но абсолютно всё про плавающую точку можно отыскать в книге `Muller, Brisebarre. Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic`, её pdf свободно валяется в интернете. Достаточно прочитать эту книгу, чтобы считать себя специалистом по данной теме. Собственно, я так и сделал: прочитал эту книгу и написал почти всю программную реализацию всех возможных плавающих типов данных от 16 до 128-битовых. Хорошая книга, там прямо всё есть.

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл ещё одну статью, с которой нужно начать, если прямо совсем-совсем не знакомы с форматом: [вот эту](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/).

Comment: Также прошу обратить внимание на мой новый сайт и соответствующий [раздел](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/) в нём. Постепенно, я доведу сайт до более удобного состояния, но читать можно уже сейчас.